# Rails find and sort, using data from a related table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have associated two models `Businesses` and `Ratings`. A business can be rated many times, and each rating stores an integer from 0 to 5.

I would like to create a "Hall of Fame" page, where I list the top 10 businesses, by sorting businesses based on average ratings (which would use the `Ratings` model) and limiting the results to 10.

I'm not sure how to write hall_of_fame method for the controller, or would I also need a helper for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have a has_many and belongs_to relationship between the two models, you can try using the (very handy) MySQL GROUP BY clause, which is supported in Rails:

```
@hall_of_fame = Business.find(
                               :all, 
                               :joins => :ratings, 
                               :group => 'business_id', 
                               :order => 'AVG(ratings.rating) DESC', 
                               :limit => 10
                             )
```

If you want to add the average rating, you can include it in a :select parameter, as such:

```
@hall_of_fame = Business.find(
                               :all,
                               :select => 'businesses.name, AVG(ratings.rating)'
                               :joins  => :ratings, 
                               :group  => 'business_id', 
                               :order  => 'AVG(ratings.rating) DESC', 
                               :limit  => 10
                             )
```

Naturally, if there are no conflicting column names between the tables, you can safely remove the leading "businesses." and "ratings." from both the :select and :order parameters.

You may want to create a method with this code in your model instead of having it in the controller, but that's up to you.

Comment: Don't for get you can use the :having option to specify a threshold.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can grab top 10 businesses with something similar to:

```
top10 = Business.average('ratings.rating', :joins => 'INNER JOIN ratings ON businesses.id = ratings.business_id', :group => 'businesses.id', :order => 'avg_ratings_rating DESC', :limit => 10 )

# example of using results of above line
top10.each { |id, avg| puts Business.find(id).name + " score: " + avg.to_s }
```

Instead of `:order =>  'avg_ratings_rating'` you can write `:order => 'avg(ratings.rating)'`. As a result it will return an ordered hash. When you iterate over it you get what you wanted.

Probably a better way is to add a class method to your Business model like this:

```
def self.getTop10
  average('ratings.rating', :joins => 'INNER JOIN ratings ON businesses.id = ratings.business_id', :group => 'businesses.id', :order => 'avg_ratings_rating DESC', :limit => 10 )
end
```

Then in controller you can do:

```
top10 = Business.getTop10
```